# Coding Style or structure for Android?

Tags: android

Coding Style or Structure for `Android`?

I need some coding structure or coding style for android, how to use object and where to declare Button and text view object etc.. Any one can help me..

I already searched in Google also.

Comment: do it as you would do it in java.

Comment: Just go out and read some tutorials, or have a look a one of plenty github android projects. There you can really learn a lot.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/page/14/. Start it from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U need button and Text view object like this..

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.MRAPS_txtProductCode)).setText(StrSelectedProductCode);
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.MRAPS_txtProductName)).setText(StrSelectedProductName);
            ((android.widget.Button)findViewById(R.id.MRAP_btnAdd)).setText("Save");
```